# MyLogin removal not working

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, 500-server-error

I am unable to delete one of my stack exchange logins entry from the list at
Edit Profile & Settings -> My Logins

The steps are the following:

1. I remove the login credentials from the "My Logins" page
2. I log out
3. I try to "log in with Stack Exchange" with the removed credentials
4. an error page appears (see image below)
5. I click on go back (browser function)
6. I click on "log in with Stack Exchange" again

At this point the system logs me in without asking for any credential and, when checking, the removed credentials reappear on the list in "My Logins".

(Note that if, after the removal, I log in with different credentials, then, as expected, the removed credentials don't appear in "My Logins")

This is the error page I get:
[image: error page]

I tried deleting cookies and history, tried logging in with a fresh browser (one I never logged in to stack exchange from) and by resetting my ip address. None of that worked!

Any suggestion on how to get rid of such a login entry?
(I need to delete it as I won't be in control of that specific e-mail any longer).

Comment: umm... just don't login with the credentials you want to remove. Why would you even do that? I guess that by logging in with them, you add them back somehow, that behavior is kind of expected.

Comment: Given access to the mail account (which won't be under my control anymore), one may request a password change, and thus be able to access my account the way I described in the question. It works. I tried. I'd like it not to be possible.

Comment: So you should delete it via the provider, e.g. Google, so that it won't be possible to use at all.

Comment: It is not a Google mail. It is a mail associated with a service I'm terminating. I can't be sure the account won't be given to someone else. I have no say in the matter. Irregardless, I don't see this as a wanted behavior. Removed login credentials should be forever decoupled from the account. Is there really no way to achieve this? Is this the expected programmed behavior?

Comment: The problem here, as far as I can tell, is the auto merge process. After you remove, and then you (or someone else) logs in again with same removed credentials, I believe a **new account** is created behind the scenes, but then auto merged with yours. Try to log in after removing from a totally different browser and see what happens.

Comment: I tried that. I also tried removing from the smartphone, restarting the router (thus getting a new ip) and then logging in with a tablet I never used on stack exchange and it still logged me in. Either the database entry doesn't get removed or there is some midway caching mechanism that doesn't get updated. I already tried waiting 4 hours between tries. I'll try waiting more.

Comment: Tried today (after more than 24 hours) and the issue still stands so it doesn't seem to be a caching problem.